# Kotlin Assignable Generic Lazy Nullabillity Problem

Tags: generics, kotlin, lazy-loading

I want to load data lazy from a database (on Android with Room)

I cannot use the lazy delegate because I need to assign the value inside my repository instead of in the POJO directly.

I want to have a function to get my value in the form `fun get(): T` with T being nullable.

The problem I face is that I need two functions if I want one returning T and one T? but only want one. My code for assignable lazy:

```
sealed class LazyDBLoad<T, D> {
    abstract fun getNullable() : T?
    abstract fun get(): T

    companion object {
        fun <T, D> of(dependency: D, onLoad: (D) -> T) : LazyDBLoad<T, D> {
            return LazyDBLoadImpl(dependency, onLoad)
        }
    }

    private class LazyDBLoadImpl<T, D>(
        private val dependency: D,
        private val onLoad: (D) -> T) : LazyDBLoad<T, D>(){

        private var wasLoaded = false
        private var loaded: T? = null

        override fun getNullable(): T? {
            if (!wasLoaded) {
                wasLoaded = true
                loaded = onLoad(dependency)
            }
            return loaded
        }

        override fun get(): T {
            return getNullable() ?: throw Exception("Not Nullable was null")
        }

    }
}
```

Usage Example:

```
var accessCount: Int = 0
val databaseResult: Int
    get() = if (accessCount < 1) {accessCount = accessCount.inc();4711} else {println("Too many accesses");-1}

fun main() {
    val dependency = Any()
    val lazyProperty: LazyDBLoad<Int, Any> = LazyDBLoad.of(dependency) {
        return@of databaseResult
    }
    val value: Int? = lazyProperty.getNullable()
    val value2: Int = lazyProperty.get()
    val lazyPropertyNull: LazyDBLoad<Int?, Any> = LazyDBLoad.of(dependency){null}
    val get = lazyPropertyNull.getNullable() //works
    val get2 = lazyPropertyNull.get() // Error but because of types no compile error
}
```

Comment: If you just throw an exception if `getNullable()` is null, why do you need `get()` function? Just delete it, rename `getNullable()` to `get()` and use `!!` operator if you need not-nullable value.

Comment: @ardenit Fair point but I would like a solution where the generic in "of" function determines the output type.

Comment: @ardenit thx, I was thinking too complicated. Now I can access it like ```var lazyProp: LazyDBLoad<Int, Any>? = null
val actualProp : Int
    get() = lazyProp!!.get()!!
```